# Org babel R : can't find org-R-apply

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, ess, r

following the tutorial http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-R/org-R.html, I get stuck because I can't find the function `org-R-apply`.

I have R installed on my computer and the package ess has been installed with usepackage (`(use-package ess :ensure t)`) which automatically does the `require`, and added the entry `(R . t)` to babel suppported languages.

I also have tried to require `ess-site` manually as it has a different name from the package, but the function is still not here.

Comment: Unfortunately that article is outdated. First paragraph says `Org-R has been replaced by Org-babel...`. `org-R-apply` is not in Org anymore. If you want to see the now deprecated code, look in [org-R.el](http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/~davison/software/org-R/org-R.el).

Comment: So what is the replacing function ? I'll probably check the .el today.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a replacement. `ob-R.el` doesn't have a similar function. It would be best to peruse `org-R.el` and copy/adapt the `org-R-apply` function manually, if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your tutorial , I have never used the `#+R` specification.

Recent (>2 years old) org-mode mainly uses code blocks to input several R lines.
Add this to your dotemacs:

```
(org-babel-do-load-languages
 'org-babel-load-languages
 '((R . t)))
```

Then in an org file `C-c C-v C-d` and select R to create a R source block. `C-c C-c` inside the block to evaluate it, `C-c <backquote>` to edit it with ess.

More info here: http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-R.html